# Shell Scripting in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, awk

I am trying to create a shell script in Linux. I have this output from a command :

**Output from Command :**

```
INSTANCE    i-fb5   ami-cee871a7        
GROUP   sg-6de  osmosix-cloud-gateway
PRIVATEIPADDRESS    10.250.168.203      
TAG instance    i-fb5   Name    CLNTONH
TAG instance    i-fb5   owner    Megha
TAG instance    i-fb5   cost.center 12345
```

This command gives me details like this. Please note that the command gives me details of all server. I have provided you with the detail of only one instance. It gives me details like this of 100 of instances/server.

I want to fetch the `TAG : Name,cost.centre,Owner and the instance id` in a **single line in this order**.

**I have used the command :**

```
ec2-describe-instances |awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/(name|owner|cost.center)/&&/tag/'
```

**Output of this command:**

```
TAG instance i-8a6  Name tli Instance
TAG instance i-576  Name RDS_Machine  Owner Jy
TAG instance i-752  Owner Ri Pdey Name Win_Ins
TAG instance i-9b3  Name s_test_VM  cost.center 0187  Owner Sachin
```

**Desired Output :**

```
TAG     instance        i-efcf      Name    Hadoop_test      Owner Naveen
```

Comment: Too much of `ec2-describe-instances` parsing these days.  Is there much point in posting the same question using different accounts?

Comment: @MeghaSharma so you want in same line means in single line output.

Comment: Try `ec2-describe-instances | grep -i "tag" | grep -i -e "name" -e "owner" -e "cost.centre" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]?a[$1FS$2FS$3] FS $4 FS $5:$4 FS $5}END{for(x in a) print x, a[x]}'`

Comment: I think you use `ec2cli` Don't use that. Use `AWS-CL` see http://aws.amazon.com/cli/ how yo use it.

Comment: @MeghaSharma Also you asked same question many times in SO. My advice you stick on one.

Comment: These commands provide a machine-readable output, for example [as json](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html). Use that instead of trying to parse the human-readable output.

Comment: @Jayesh you left four comments in a row; that obscures further comments. I'd suggest you try consolidating what you want to say in fewer comments.