# Error in shell script and how to write to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am writing a shell script that is extracting the data from a command:

I have tried running the script in both the vi and vim editor. But everything in vain.

Please help me out. And how write the output of this in a file.

It may be noted that this is just a starting point so the script will produce multiple files so 
I cannot write:

```
Script_name > filename
```

Comment: It's pointless to post scores of questions (as multiple users) across multiple sites for one problem.  Spend some time visiting the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and see help on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Show us some sample output from `ec2-describe-instances`.  Most people won't have that, so we can't even begin to guess what you're trying to parse.  Since you want multiple outputs, you'd better show two or three units of the input that should be processed, and you should show the output you expect from it.  Without that information, (this variation of) your question is unanswerable.

Comment: One related previous question from Megha on SO was [Shell scripting in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677477/shell-scripting-in-linux).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : sir the way the output is being outputted is fine, see above but I am not able to get the details of all instances. I have tried the script in vim and vi editor.But nothing is working

Comment: please note that the ec2-describe command produces details of all the instances but I have given details of only few inatnces

Comment: But we still don't know what you expect to get from the input you show. Your example output does not correspond to any of the data in the sample input. Only one of the four reservations has a cost centre tag; what do you want generated for the others? We are not miracle workers; if you can't tell us what you want, we can't give you what you want. Even if you do tell us, it may not be possible, but at least we'll be able to say so confidently.

Comment: Question updated. actually some tags are missing in the servers that is why

Comment: Now there's a chance that maybe someone can help you, but 'tis bedtime here. Please note that it should not take this much chivvying to get you to produce an answerable question. You should have thought through what you're asking — what are the people who will help me going to need to be able to provide me with the answer. Let's think: input data; expected output; malfunctioning script; output from malfunctioning script — yes, that's about what it takes. We can run the script on the data and see what it produces; your info confirms that we see what you see, so that's good.

Comment: Well, it should be bedtime...I took the data and made it into a script `ec2-describe-instances` and ran your Korn shell script (with Korn shell, Bash, `zsh` and `sh` — which is a link to `bash`) and it produced precisely your desired output.  So, the problem is back in your court — how are you running your code, and exactly what output do you get from the data you show?  Which version of `awk` are you using.  Etc.

Comment: Just tried your script. It produces exactly the wanted output. so..

Comment: @Jonathan:but sir when I run as a bash this script does not work. I am using the centos amazon sir.

Comment: @jm666: Hi I would like to know what you have done to run the script as it is not giving me the required output

Comment: @MeghaSharma: All I did was copy the script from the question with copy and pasted it into `cat > parser.sh` in a terminal (and typed control-D to finish the file). I then made sure that the file `ec2-describe-instances`, which contained `cat <<'EOF' … EOF` with your data in between was executable, and then ran: `PATH=$PWD:$PATH ksh parser.sh` (and repeated for the various other shells I tried — I don't have the Heirloom Bourne Shell on this machine or I'd've used that too — anything that isn't a C shell should handle it). So, verify that you're executing the script you think you're executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is fine now, the input file is good enough after edit, I can fully understand what you ask for now.

With awk, you need learn to use 2-d array, it will simplify the code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Instance id           Name                      Owner         Cost.centre"}
/TAG/{split($0,a,FS);a[4]=tolower(a[4]);$1=$2=$3=$4="";b[a[3],a[4]]=$0;c[a[3]]}
END{for (i in c) printf "%-18s%-26s%-14s%-20s\n",i,b[i,"name"],b[i,"owner"],b[i,"cost.center"]}' file

Instance id           Name                      Owner         Cost.centre
i-e1cfc499            Memcached                                               
i-7f4b9300            Test_LB01_Sachin                                        
i-c4260db8            Rishi_Win_SAML            Rishi Pandey                    
i-fb5ca283            CLIQR-DO NOT TOUCH        mataa         1234
```

Comment: there is formatting issue. can you please tell me why my script is not working? What is the issue? some people are saying that my script is working fine for them