# Please help modifying the shell script in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-io

I have a shell script that do the following task:

1. extract the tags(name,owner,cost.centre) from `ec2-describe-instances` commands and write this detail to a file.
2. Also finds the instances whose any above mentioned tag is missing and write the data in another file.

Any lead is appreciated

Comment: Yes I have created a function `pr()`. Actually the data is fetched from `ec2-describe-instances` command whose first element of each record is `reservations`. Do you want me to provide you with sample output of this command

Comment: the `BEGIN` function is printing some text in the `Instance Details` file like heading, headers. And `END`is printing the result of the last instance. I will provide detail of a single instance.

Comment: as you can see the output of `instance details`  file has been formatted using format specifier as it was very difficult to read the data

Comment: Have you read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html? It provides a lot of options to get specific data. So there's no need to parse the entire output at once.

Comment: yeah I have read that but the filters were not really helpful. I have tried a lot. but everything in vain.

Comment: Sorry! Forget my comments. I completely missed you were using `awk` within your script! EDIT: I deleted them - they were too misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget yours, I have recommended to use 2-d array in awk to simplify the code.

Here is the updates from your previous question ([Error in shell script and how to write to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778444/error-in-shell-script-and-how-to-write-to-a-file/22781871#22781871))

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Instance id           Name                      Owner         Cost.centre"}
/TAG/{split($0,a,FS);a[4]=tolower(a[4]);$1=$2=$3=$4="";b[a[3],a[4]]=$0;c[a[3]]}
END{for (i in c) printf "%-18s%-26s%-14s%-20s\n",i,b[i,"name"]==""?"Unknown":b[i,"name"],b[i,"owner"]==""?"Unknown":b[i,"owner"],b[i,"cost.center"]==""?"Unknown":b[i,"cost.center"]}' file
```

Comment: This code is giving me all the server details who have even the all the tags. I want details of only servers that have any tag missing with the missing tags replaced by unknown

Comment: you can still run it, and grep the output with keyword `Unknown`, which will give you the server list which has no full information

Comment: It will result in two files which I don't want.also the output is not very formatted.

Comment: formatting is your task, you need spend time to work it out. the awk commmand | grep "Unknown" > file will generate only one output file.